# If Statement with numbers goes wrong

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

Ok there, I'm trying to make a batch that have to read some `.txt` files and to create some `.ics`s that I should load on Google Calendar.

Year and month are set manually, and it have to go from 1 to 30 for the days.

What the batch do is this:

-Set the day (`d`);

-Update date (`data`), input name file (`in`) and output name file (`out`);

-Read all the lines and create an event for all the day long with the lines as name of the events.

And this work should have done from `20141101.txt` to `20141130.txt`, creating files from `20141101.ics` to `20141130.ics`.

I post the code and the problem just below.

Code:

```
@echo off
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "y=2014"
set "m=11"
set "d=00"
set /A "prova=10"
set "data=!y!!m!!d!"
set "in=!data!.txt"
set "out=!data!.ics"
for /L %%i in (0,1,11) do (
    if "%%i" LSS "!prova!" (
        set "d=0%%i"
    ) else (
        set "d=%%i"
    )
    echo !d!
    set "data=!y!!m!!d!"
    set "in=!data!.txt"
    set "out=!data!.ics"
    echo BEGIN:VCALENDAR>>!out!
    for /F "tokens=*" %%l in (!in!) do (
        echo BEGIN:VEVENT>>!out!
        echo DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:!data!>>!out!
        echo SUMMARY:%%l>>!out!
        echo END:VEVENT>>!out!
    )
    echo END:VCALENDAR>>!out!
)
pause
goTo :exit

:exit
    exit
```

Problem:
The if statement that have to control if the day is less than 10 works only for `d` equal to `0` and `1` and I just don't understand why.

`echo  !d!` prints `00`, `01`, `3`, `4`, ..., `9`, `10`, `11` and only for `d=0` and `d=1` the if statement is respected...

I tried to set `d` with and without `/A` in the set command, but never changed...

What am I doing wrong?
Any tip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

The right statement should be written like this:

```
if %%i LSS !prova! (
    set "d=0%%i"
) else (
    set "d=%%i"
)
```

[The problem were the quotation marks that forced the statement to use the vars as they were strings]

For everybody who wants to use the same code and editing it I leave it here.